# How to re-factor WindowInteropHelper to a VM method?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, oauth

I'm following a sample WPF app from [auth0](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-winforms-wpf-sample/blob/master/WpfSample/MainWindow.xaml.cs) using a login provider in WPF, and trying to use the code in my MVVM project. But I'm not sure how to refactor the `button click` code to a method that can be used in the ViewModel.

I've cut the code into a void method, and the error I get is on `new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle` as follows:

```
"Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper.WindowInteropHelper(System.Windows.Window)' has some invalid arguments"

"Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDBApp.ViewModels.LoginViewModel' to 'System.Windows.Window'"
```

I understand from the error that the code is Window specific. Does anyone know how I can re-factor that code to a void method?

This is the button click event from the example:

```
    private void LoginWithWidget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        auth0.LoginAsync(new WindowWrapper(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
                this.textBox1.Text = t.Exception.InnerException.ToString();
            else
                this.textBox1.Text = t.Result.Profile.ToString();
        },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

And this is my refactor of the code to a method, but there is an error using the `WindowInteropHelper` code:

```
    private void LoginCustomer(object l)
    {

        auth0.LoginAsync(new WindowWrapper(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed!: ", "Not Logged In", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Login succesfull!: ", "Logged In", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        },
       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

This is the [API provider's site](https://auth0.com/docs/native-platforms/wpf-winforms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to do this is by using ICommand.

Create a Class that implements ICommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand 
{
     public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
       : this(execute, null)
   {
   }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

I won't bloat the answer with all the boilerplate code you need, you can find that here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example

You could also follow that tutorial, it pretty much sums up what you want to achieve.

Then in your ViewModel you have your ICommand handlers:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ICommand LoginCommand{get; private set;}

    public MyViewModel
    {
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => DoSomething );
    }

    public void DoSomething(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally, bind it up in the Xaml View:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

This is rougly how the code should work. Follow that example though, it will give you a better understanding.